# Excel Addin and overriding save keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, excel-2007, office-addins

Currently I've inherited a Word/Excel addin project that does a custom save process.  The project is in VS2010 and Excel/Word 2007

In the word addin, the following xml is being passed back GetCustomUI call, defining our custom functionality

```
<commands>
  <command idMso="FileOpen" onAction="WordAddinOpen" />
  <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="WordAddinSave" />
  <command idMso="FileSaveAs" onAction="WordAddinSaveAs" />
</commands>
```

When I put a breakpoint in my WordAddinSave function, and click either the save icon or press Control-S, the code stops at my breakpoint.  The same happens if I put a breakpoint in my open functionality and press Control-O

In the Excel addin, I have similar xml being passed back

```
<commands>
  <command idMso="FileOpen" onAction="ExcelAddinOpen" />
  <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="ExcelAddinSave" />
  <command idMso="FileSaveAs" onAction="ExcelAddinSaveAs" />
</commands>
```

But, if I put a breakpoint in my ExcelAddinSave function, the code only stops if I click on the save icon, but not the keyboard shortcuts.  If I press Control-S or Control-O, the default Excel behavour of saving/opening file happens, instead of my custom functionality.

The ExcelAddinSave/ExcelAddinOpen is defined in a class that inherits BaseRibbon and implements Office.IRibbonExtensibility, as follows:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class CExcelRibbon : BaseRibbon, Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    public CExcelRibbon()
    {
    }

    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return GetResourceText(asm, "CExcelRibbon.xml");  //defines custom functionality
    }

    public void ExcelAddinOpen(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancel)
    {
        //custom open functionality snipped
    }


    public void ExcelAddinSave(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancel)
    {
      //custom save functionality snipped
    }

    //remaining class functionality snipped
}
```

Because I've inherited this project, I'm not the expert in Office Addins, but why doesn't the excel call my Excel addin functionality on the keyboard shortcuts Control-S/Control-O?

**Note:**

The current functionality is setting up a SetWindowsHookEx keyboard hook to preview all keypresses for a Control-S/Control-O.  However, due to our environment, this looks like to be an issue, as it appears Windows 7 is disconnecting our key press hook due it taking too long.  I've tested it with the following reg key set, and it stays.  However, long term I'd like to find a more optimal solution

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LowLevelHooksTimeout
```